# VBA how to show 1 value from 1 cell in USER form

Tags: vba, excel, userform

this is definitely a beginners question.

I would like to know how can I show in my userform only 1 value.

I have tried following but it wont go through - it needs at least 2 values.

```
ListBox.List = Application.Worksheets("Můj_Ranking").Range("Y5").Value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `.AddItem` :

```
ListBox.AddItem Application.Worksheets("Můj_Ranking").Range("Y5").Value
```

Comment: Sorry,I have left out that Rank is a List box. I need to sho it in my user form, but I dont know how.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Dont you know whether there is a possibility to reduce scrollbar? It always shows even there is no more data and it is not necessary to have it there.

Comment: Okey, there is no need :) I see it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638129/remove-the-scroll-bar-on-a-list-box